# NSInternalInconsistencyException occurring sometimes when performing setContent

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscollectionview

I use `NSCollectionView` with Content Array (Legacy) layout, so I need `setContent:` only to change the collection view items while they are build by a `NSLibraryGridItem` subclass and a .xib file. However, some of my users are receiving crashes when `setContent:` is called, but very rarely. This is the crash log:

```
Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[5520]: garbage collection is OFF
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[NSViewController loadView] could not load the "(null)" nib.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff843b4f56 __exceptionPreprocess 198
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff895bfd5e objc_exception_throw 43
2 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff843b4d8a [NSException raise:format:arguments:] 106
3 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff843b4d14 [NSException raise:format:] 116
4 AppKit 0x00007fff8630b1b5 -[NSViewController loadView] 336
5 AppKit 0x00007fff86306dfe -[NSViewController view] 41
6 AppKit 0x00007fff8694c425 -[NSCollectionViewItem _copyConnectionsToItem:] 49
7 AppKit 0x00007fff8694c9d9 -[NSCollectionViewItem copyWithZone:] 541
8 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8435cd54 -[NSObject copy] 20
9 AppKit 0x00007fff869560c7 -[NSCollectionView newItemForRepresentedObject:] 63
10 AppKit 0x00007fff8695047a -[NSCollectionView _getItemsToDisplay] 1406
11 AppKit 0x00007fff869568f4 -[NSCollectionView setContent:] 275
12 MyApp 0x00000001068a1879 _mh_execute_header 112761
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff89486a82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release 18
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff894888f2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF 308
15 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff84349e7c __CFRunLoopRun 1724
16 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff84349486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific 230
17 HIToolbox 0x00007fff89b172bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode 277
18 HIToolbox 0x00007fff89b1e56d ReceiveNextEventCommon 355
19 HIToolbox 0x00007fff89b1e3fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode 62
20 AppKit 0x00007fff861da779 _DPSNextEvent 659
21 AppKit 0x00007fff861da07d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] 135
22 AppKit 0x00007fff861d69b9 -[NSApplication run] 470
23 AppKit 0x00007fff86452eac NSApplicationMain 867
24 MyApp 0x0000000106887d38 _mh_execute_header 7480
25 ??? 0x0000000000000002 0x0 2
)

terminate called throwing an exception
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff89fdfce2 __pthread_kill 10
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff86e8e7d2 pthread_kill 95
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff86e7fa7a abort 143
3 libc abi.dylib 0x00007fff8753c7bc abort_message 214
4 libc abi.dylib 0x00007fff87539fcf default_terminate() 28
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff895c01b9 _objc_terminate 94
6 libc abi.dylib 0x00007fff8753a001 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) 11
7 libc abi.dylib 0x00007fff8753a05c std::terminate() 16
8 libc abi.dylib 0x00007fff8753b152 __cxa_throw 114
9 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff895bfe7a objc_exception_throw 327
10 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff843b4d8a [NSException raise:format:arguments:] 106
11 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff843b4d14 [NSException raise:format:] 116
12 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff8630b1b5 -[NSViewController loadView] 336
13 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff86306dfe -[NSViewController view] 41
14 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff8694c425 -[NSCollectionViewItem _copyConnectionsToItem:] 49
15 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff8694c9d9 -[NSCollectionViewItem copyWithZone:] 541
16 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8435cd54 -[NSObject copy] 20
17 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff869560c7 -[NSCollectionView newItemForRepresentedObject:] 63
18 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff8695047a -[NSCollectionView _getItemsToDisplay] 1406
19 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff869568f4 -[NSCollectionView setContent:] 275
20 MyApp 0x00000001068a1879 0x106886000 112761
21 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff89486a82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release 18
22 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff894888f2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF 308
23 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff84349e7c __CFRunLoopRun 1724
24 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff84349486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific 230
25 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff89b172bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode 277
26 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff89b1e56d ReceiveNextEventCommon 355
27 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff89b1e3fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode 62
28 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff861da779 _DPSNextEvent 659
29 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff861da07d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] 135
30 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff861d69b9 -[NSApplication run] 470
31 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff86452eac NSApplicationMain 867
32 MyApp 0x0000000106887d38 0x106886000 7480
```

With me the app works normally, and the users that received the crash were only doing regular things, which means that there is apparently no special condition that causes the crash, and that I can't reproduce the bug.

An important information: my app needs to support macOS 10.6, so I can only use solutions that support that system.

**EDIT (30/08/2017):**

The problem still wasn't solved. I've made that to avoid the crash, but I still don't know the origin of it:

```
-(BOOL)safeSetContent:(NSArray*)newContent
{
    @try
    {
        [self setContent:newContent];
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

        return YES;
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception)
    {
        if (exception.name == NSInternalInconsistencyException)
        {
            [NSAlert showAlertOfType:NSAlertTypeError withMessage:@"An unexpected NSInternalInconsistencyException occured."];
            return NO;
        }

        [NSAlert showAlertMessageWithException:exception];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

It's important to say that I don't use `NSViewController` in any part of my code (the project was created during the Mac OS X 10.6 era, and it wasn't default back there).

And these are three functions that call `safeSetContent:`:

```
-(void)forceReloadTableContents
{
    NSArray* contentArray = self.appsArray.tabType == DEFAULT_TYPE ? @[DEFAULT_VALUE] : nil;

    [NSThread dispatchBlockInMainQueue:^
    {
        if ([self safeSetContent:contentArray])
        {
            [NSThread dispatchQueueWithName:THREAD_RELOAD_GRID_VIEW_AFTER_SAVE
                                   priority:DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT concurrent:NO withBlock:^
            {
                [self reloadTableContents];
            }];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)reloadTableWithType:(NSInteger)type
{
    [self safeSetContent:@[]];

    if (type == DEFAULT_TYPE)
    {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadDefaultType) toTarget:self.libraryTabView withObject:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [(NSLibraryTabView*)self.libraryTabView loadOtherType];
    }
}

-(void)reloadTableContents
{
    BOOL isServer = (self.appsArray.tabType == DEFAULT_TYPE);
    NSMutableArray* contentArray = isServer ? [@[DEFAULT_VALUE] mutableCopy] : [@[] mutableCopy];
    if (self.appsArray.array) [contentArray addObjectsFromArray:self.appsArray.array];
    if (contentArray.count == 0) contentArray = nil;

    [NSThread dispatchBlockInMainQueue:^
    {
        if ([self safeSetContent:contentArray])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:COLLECTION_VIEW_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

I've changed the name of some variables.

The bug has been observed in multiple macOS versions, from 10.6 to 10.12.

I guess this is my `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass relevant content:

```
@implementation NSLibraryGridItem

-(NSDictionary*)representedDictionary
{
    if (!self.representedObject) return nil;

    return (NSDictionary*)[self.representedObject copy];
}
-(void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

    NSDictionary* info = self.representedDictionary;

    if (info)
    {
        if ([info isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            // App logic
        }
    }
}

@end
```

And `NSLibraryGridItem` is chosen as the view during the collection view `awakeFromNib` with that:

```
self.collectionViewItem = [NSLibraryGridItem new];
[self setItemPrototype:self.collectionViewItem];
```

Comment: Here's the important phrase in all that:  `reason: '-[NSViewController loadView] could not load the "(null)" nib`.  Also note that it's nearly impossible to diagnose or fix without seeing code.  I'd look for someplace where a collection view is trying to get a view controller's view to present.

Comment: I guess this is also a important point: I don't have code related with view controllers in my app. Is it possible that the xib file (which technically have a nib file inside) is failing to be loaded sometimes, and this is causing the problem?

Comment: I will check what I can show of the code, but I can't show much

Comment: `NSCollectionViewItem` is a subclass of `NSViewController`, so that's why you're seeing `NSViewController` in the trace. Can you post the code that calls `-safeSetContent:`? Particularly, what is in the `newContent` array?

Comment: Also, do the crashes tend to occur only on some particular version of macOS / OS X, or do they occur on multiple versions?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka just added the functions that call `safeSetContent:`. `newContent ` is always an array of dictionaries or nil.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wonder if you could post the code of your `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass, if you're using one? If not, how are you translating the dictionaries into the views to be displayed in the collection view?

Comment: Just added my `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass, or at least the part that is relevant.

Comment: The part that I'm curious about, actually, is the part that determines the view that is displayed. Could you post that? What it looks like to me, from your trace, is that `NSCollectionViewItem` sometimes doesn't know what its view is, so it tries to load a nonexistent nib file, leading to the exception being thrown.

Comment: I simply have a `NSLibraryGridItem.xib` file with the view. Since it has the same name of the class it is loaded. Its `File's Owner` is of the `NSLibraryGridItem` class by the way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the behavior of `NSViewController` which causes it to automatically load a xib file with the same name as the `NSViewController` subclass is only documented to work reliably on OS X 10.10 and higher, whereas on older versions it results in undefined behavior:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_10ViewController

Since you are targeting 10.6, you need to specify the nib name manually. You can do this by adding an override to the `nibName` property in your `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass. This *should*, I think, fix your problem, since the exception you're getting is complaining about not knowing the name of the nib it needs to load, and since "undefined behavior" certainly seems to describe the non-reproducibility of your problem.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know if it works :)

Comment: For some reason, when using nibName, my `NSTextField` property in the `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass is nil, even if it's connected in the xib file... If I remove the nibName override it starts working again.

Comment: I also have 4 `NSImageView`, 1 `NSProgressIndicator` and 1 `NSButton`, but only the `NSTextField` becomes nil.

Comment: Tried changing the `NSTextField` name and making it not a property. None worked :P

Comment: Is the property named `textField`? If so, maybe name it something else, since there's a 10.7-and-up-only property by that name on `NSCollectionViewItem` already that you might be butting heads against.

Comment: The property is named `itemNameField`. I tried to name it `itemAppNameField` as well, but it was no use. I've checked the connections in the xib; they are good. Like I said, it works without the nibName override.

Comment: Try running Clean All and rebuilding the app from scratch. The nib file that's been copied into the app may have been corrupted.

Comment: Performed a Clean (Cmd + Shift + K) and have build and run (Cmd + R) the project. No difference :( The text field still works if I remove the `nibName` override though.

Comment: It's hard for me to diagnose this without being able to see your project or your application structure, but I'll bet something is wonky with either your nib or your xib file, although it's hard for me to guess exactly what. Here are a few things I might recommend:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153299/discussion-between-charles-srstka-and-vitormm).

Comment: For posterity: Problem turned out to be that the check for the text field property was occurring in a method that was being called before the `NSCollectionViewItem`'s `loadView` was being called, and thus all of its outlets were nil at that time. Calling the relevant setup code from `loadView` (with the caveat to change to `viewDidLoad` at such time as the project can require Yosemite) solved the issue.

Comment: Just received three reports. The message now says `-[NSViewController loadView] could not load the "NSLibraryGridItem" nib.` :P

Comment: You've gotta be kidding me. What's the full text of the exception? Is it complaining about missing classes or anything like that?

Comment: Also, check the File Inspector in Interface Builder and see if "Builds For" is not set to your deployment target, OS X 10.6.

Comment: I don't have access to the full text. This is what I retrieved with the Google Analytics API. It's all that I have.

Comment: My app as two version: a regular and a legacy one. The regular one is compatible with 10.8+ and the legacy one is compatible with 10.6+. In both cases, "Builds For" is set for the "Deployment Target", so it's 10.6/10.8 for Legacy/Regular version.

Comment: The message is the exception reason

Comment: This may be a silly question, but can you check to make sure the nib file's being included in both versions? `/usr/bin/find /path/to/app -iname \*.nib`

Comment: Also, maybe temporarily set the "Deployment Target" to straight-up 10.6 for now, so that it'll warn if anything that's not 10.6-compatible is being used in there, even when building your normal debug builds.

Comment: I guess you mean `\*.nib`. Yes it's. Just checked. As I said, the app works properly in my computers with macOS 10.12 and Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: D'oh, I did mean .nib. This is super weird, so I'm grasping at straws a bit here, but what are the permissions on the nib files inside the built versions of the apps?

Comment: Tried changing "Build For" to 10.6. The only warning produced was "This file is set to build for a version older than the deployment target. Functionality may be limited."

Comment: Regular version: -rw-r--r--   1 vitor  staff     5707 31 Ago 11:30 NSLibraryGridItem.nib

Comment: Legacy version: -rw-r--r--   1 vitor  staff     5707 31 Ago 11:33 NSLibraryGridItem.nib

Comment: That of course looks right. Hrm. How complicated is this xib file? Is it feasible to recreate it from scratch in case something in it is corrupted somehow?

Comment: It's pretty simple. Some image views, a spinner, a text field and a button.

Comment: It isn't hard to recreate it from scratch

Comment: Maybe try recreating the .xib file. It's a long shot, but hey, it might work. Also, on your 10.6 machine, see how many variations you can think of to run the app; maybe drag it around to various folders on your hard drive, put it in a path with weird Unicode characters in one of the parent folders, run it straight from the .dmg if you use one, etc. to see if it will reproduce with any particular variations.

Comment: Also, you can try overriding `nibBundle` as well as `nibName`. I can't think of any good reason why that wouldn't work with the default setting, but what the hell, anything's worth trying at this point.

Comment: But I don't use the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method. Based in the documentation it doesn't seems to apply to my case. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434433-nibbundle?language=objc

Comment: Also, the error is produced by both legacy and regular versions, and the old crash logs with `(null)` used to happen in any folder; usually the Downloads folder and the Desktop.

Comment: `initWithNibName:bundle:` is the designated initializer for `NSViewController`; it's getting called by something internally at some point. `NSViewController` uses the `nibBundle` property to get an `NSBundle` to load the nib from; if it's nil, it *should* be defaulting to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, but what the hell, won't hurt to make it explicit.

Comment: Recreating the .xib is the main thing I'd try at this point, though. It's voodoo, but it might work, who knows.

Comment: So I should recreate the `xib` file and override `nibBundle` with `[NSBundle mainBundle]`? Just to confirm

Comment: That's what I'd try doing.